# trimming using substr and instr function

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table customer. Contains cus_info as 'ceg_cus_hongkong_21032015_HHMISS'.
I need only the country name from the following mentioned string that is hongkong. And this will be generic for all data provided in cus_info column.
Please help me out how can it be possible using substr?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  substr(cus_info,
     instr(cus_info ,'_', 1, 2),
     ( 
        instr(cus_info ,'_', 1, 3)  -- position of 3rd _
        -
        instr('cus_info ,'_', 1, 2)  -- position of 2nd _
      )
  )
from customer
```